# What is the recommended method to prepare Red Hat/CentOS 7 templates?

Tags: centos, virtualization, redhat, disk-image, templates

If I need to deploy Red Hat 7 from template, I would like to take the recommended steps to make my "golden image" clean. It should boot to the [first boot prompt](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-initial-setup-firstboot.html) and guide the user through the typical steps.

In Red Hat 5/6, I [followed the documentation provided](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.5/html/User_Guide/sect-Templates.html#sect-Sealing_Templates_in_Preparation_for_Deployment) by the vendor. However, I cannot find the equivalent for Red Hat 7. Specifically, `touch /.unconfigured` does not trigger the first boot setup.

> ### 9.3.1. Sealing a Linux Virtual Machine for Deployment as a Template
>
> **Summary**
>   Generalize (seal) a Linux virtual machine before making it into a template. This prevents conflicts between virtual machines deployed from the template.
>
> **Procedure 9.6. Sealing a Linux Virtual Machine**
>
> Log in to the virtual machine. Flag the system for re-configuration by running the following command as root:
>
> 1. **`# touch /.unconfigured`**
> 2. Remove ssh host keys. Run:
>      **`# rm -rf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*`**
> 3. Set **`HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain`** in **`/etc/sysconfig/network`**
> 4. Remove /etc/udev/rules.d/70-*. Run:
>      **`# rm -rf /etc/udev/rules.d/70-*`**
> 5. Remove the **HWADDR=** and **UUID=** line from **`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`**.
> 6. Optionally delete all the logs from **`/var/log`** and build logs from **`/root`**.
> 7. Shut down the virtual machine. Run:
>      **`# poweroff`**

**Edit:** Steps 1 & 7 can be combined by running `sys-unconfig` last. Or, have a look at `virt-sysprep` from **libguestfs-tools-c** which does much, much more.

```
 [user@hostname ~]$ virt-sysprep --list-operations
 abrt-data * Remove the crash data generated by ABRT
 bash-history * Remove the bash history in the guest
 blkid-tab * Remove blkid tab in the guest
 ca-certificates   Remove CA certificates in the guest
 crash-data * Remove the crash data generated by kexec-tools
 cron-spool * Remove user at-jobs and cron-jobs
 delete * Delete specified files or directories
 dhcp-client-state * Remove DHCP client leases
 dhcp-server-state * Remove DHCP server leases
 dovecot-data * Remove Dovecot (mail server) data
 firewall-rules   Remove the firewall rules
 firstboot * Add scripts to run once at next boot
 flag-reconfiguration   Flag the system for reconfiguration
 hostname * Change the hostname of the guest
 kerberos-data   Remove Kerberos data in the guest
 logfiles * Remove many log files from the guest
 lvm-uuids * Change LVM2 PV and VG UUIDs
 machine-id * Remove the local machine ID
 mail-spool * Remove email from the local mail spool directory
 net-hostname * Remove HOSTNAME in network interface configuration
 net-hwaddr * Remove HWADDR (hard-coded MAC address) configuration
 pacct-log * Remove the process accounting log files
 package-manager-cache * Remove package manager cache
 pam-data * Remove the PAM data in the guest
 password * Set root or user password
 puppet-data-log * Remove the data and log files of puppet
 random-seed * Generate random seed for guest
 rhn-systemid * Remove the RHN system ID
 rpm-db * Remove host-specific RPM database files
 samba-db-log * Remove the database and log files of Samba
 script * Run arbitrary scripts against the guest
 smolt-uuid * Remove the Smolt hardware UUID
 ssh-hostkeys * Remove the SSH host keys in the guest
 ssh-userdir * Remove ".ssh" directories in the guest
 sssd-db-log * Remove the database and log files of sssd
 tmp-files * Remove temporary files
 udev-persistent-net * Remove udev persistent net rules
 user-account   Remove the user accounts in the guest
 utmp * Remove the utmp file
 yum-uuid * Remove the yum UUID
```

Comment: Almost had it. Setting `RUN_FIRSTBOOT=YES` in `/etc/sysconfig/firstboot` got me the Kdump configuration part, but not the rest of the Firstboot process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What we think of as the initial setup is actually in three parts. The first two are:

- Initial setup, which asks you to accept the license and create a user
- Firstboot, which asks you to configure kdump and (on RHEL) set up your subscription

Both of these are now enabled via systemd; once complete they disable themselves.

So, all you should have to do is remove any local user(s) created during the first Initial Setup process and re-enable these services:

```
systemctl enable initial-setup-graphical.service
systemctl enable firstboot-graphical.service
> /etc/sysconfig/firstboot
```

and reboot.

I'm not *entirely* sure about the third part, which asks you for your language and to create a user account or to to join the machine to a domain. This, at least, will continue coming back until you actually complete the wizard. (So don't do that.)

It still may be a good idea to clean-up host keys and any hardware specific configuration. (Mac addresses in udev rules and interface configuration files.)

Comment: Figured it out... You can't have any users other than 'root'. I had been using the user created the first time through the Initial Setup process. Logged in as root, userdel'd the user and rebooted -- Initial Setup worked.

Comment: Ah, I never create local users because I'm generally joining a domain. Figures.