# Preparing CentOS 7 as a virtual machine

Tags: networking, virtualization, centos7

I've removed the `HWADDR` from `ifcfg-eth0` and touched `/.unconfigured`, but when I restart the virtual machine, HWADDR is not added back to the ifcfg-eth0. Is there something else we should be doing?

Comment: Did you try this already? http://serverfault.com/q/626889/50647

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I tried the above link, but it doesn't recreate the HWADDR line.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm trying to prep a CentOS machine for virtualization. I don't want cloned machines to try using the same hardware address.

Comment: I'm not sure if I experienced that or not.. Most of my VMs only have a single interface, so I have no issue leaving that line out of the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `HWADDR` does not get set automatically. It's only in `ifcfg-XXX` so you can tie a particular network configuration to a particular card. If you only have one interface, `HWADDR` is not needed in `ifcfg-XXX`