# sys-unconfig equivalent for Fedora 30

Tags: kvm-virtualization, fedora, proxmox, template

I'm trying to prepare a Fedora 30 KVM virtual machine template on Proxmox.
I wanted to use the sys-unconfig command but it was [removed in initscripts 9.81-1](https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-x86_64/initscripts-10.01-2.fc30.x86_64.rpm.html)
virt-sysprep failed when I ran it from Proxmox host.
What is the alternative for Fedora 30?

Comment: I suspect that `virt-sysprep` is the intended method. Could we look into why it failed? (What error did you get?) That's the string I'd be pulling on.

Comment: I need to check again but I prefer to run it from the guest OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that sys-unconfig is just a script in the following way:
I started CentOS 7 docker container on my computer

```
docker run -it centos:latest
```

then:

```
yum whatprovides sys-unconfig
```

then I found the package:

```
initscripts-9.49.46-1.el7.x86_64 : The inittab file and the /etc/init.d scripts
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/sys-unconfig
```

installed it:

```
yum install initscripts -y
```

then I found the script contents:

```
cat /usr/sbin/sys-unconfig
#!/bin/sh

. /etc/init.d/functions

if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
    echo $"Usage: sys-unconfig" >&2
    exit 1
fi

touch /.unconfigured
rm -f /etc/udev/rules.d/*-persistent-*.rules
poweroff
```

Comment: This is just 2 of many things that should be done. [Look into what all `virt-sysprep` does](https://serverfault.com/q/626889/50647).